# extjs: fieldset- setting the style of expand/collapse icon while setting blank title for the fieldset comp

Tags: extjs, icons, fieldset

I defined a fieldset while setting blank title. however, in browser, the fieldset has a expand/collapse icon in right-top corner, while i want have it in left-top corner? what I am supposed to do?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it on the left corner like any normal fieldset with a title with some trick. You can get what you need by using unicode for "Narrow No-Break Space". The unicode is U+202F. So in your code, you will have to set your title as:

```
title: '\u202F',
```

keep in mind that you cannot completely box the fieldset with this trick. Here is a small gap in the fieldset border on the right side of the collapse button. You could also use other unicode characters like `\u200B`,`\u200C` etc. But they all provided me with the same result.

You can get a more better result by removing the CSS style `right-margin: 3px` applied to the legned of fieldset. I haven't tried to do that though.